# Flow chart of all the data in windows/linux

Tags: linux, database, windows, user-interface

Is there a way to view the flow chart of data representation in windows or linux, I mean for example directory is basically a file indexing files can all this be represented in a gui?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Generally windows has a GUI, called windows explorer, and depending on your setup for linux you have similar. When you say GUI what type of representation do you want? Generally you can display your data however you want, but your question doesn't make a lot of sense as it stands. There are various charts for data usage in the control panel as well.

Comment: I mean all an WE does not say show where the "directory file" is stored in storage, and also the whole system is a simple db so if its another db why cant we plot a Flow/Er diagram for it?

Comment: Not really a "simple db" you probably should read up on File systems, particularly NTFS, FAT, and EXT...